# How to install multiple php versions on a single docker container

Tags: php, nginx, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have started using docker recently and were able to setup two containers one is running php7.0 with apache2 and another running mysql both of them are able to talk to each other and everything is working fine, now I want to setup a new docker container which shoudl have nginx, php5.6-fpm and php7.0-fpm installed on single container I have been trying to achieve it since past few hours with no luck. Following is my Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:latest
FROM php:php7.1-fpm
FROM php:php5.6-fpm
COPY ./src /var/www/html
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    nano \
    git \
    zip \
    mcrypt \
&& docker-php-ext-install mcrypt \
&& docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
&& docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
&& curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
```

**EDIT: **

I know that one container should have one responsibility but I am in a situation where I need both php5.6-fpm and php7.1-fpm to be running simultaneously, I can create three containers i.e with php5.6-fpm with php7.1-fpm and nginx how would I tell nginx to look for a folder in the conatainer which is running php5.6-fpm if someone tries to access hostone.dev etc

Comment: what is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

A main philosophy of Docker is to have one task (or process) per container. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/ for more clarification on this.

I would question whether you're making the most of Docker by trying to run so much in one container. It's alright to run PHP and Apache in the same container (there's an official image for this!), but I'd advise against running nginx and PHP FPM in the same container because PHP FPM is its own process and should therefore get its own container.

Secondly, I think you're misusing the multiple `FROM` feature.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from:

> FROM can appear multiple times within a single Dockerfile in order to create multiple images. Simply make a note of the last image ID output by the commit before each new FROM command.

The `FROM` keyword specifies a base image, which you build on top of. If you want a single image as an output, you need a single base image to build on. If your base image is `php:7.1-fpm`, you will need to manually install the other version of PHP that you want. This may prove difficult as they'll conflict in a lot of places. I'd strongly recommend rethinking your design and using two separate containers, or running your PHP 5 code with PHP 7 - it's *mostly* backwards compatible.